# Why wouldn't FACEIT Counterstrike be the same as MM in the long run?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-2

Here's what I understand:

- Regular *CSGO*/*CS2* matchmaking aka 'MM' has no intrusive anti-cheat.
- FACEIT has intrusive anti-cheat but is very toxic. Usually, you're here only if you're at least Gold Nova 1, i.e. not silver.

**Question: Not sure of the starting rank or rating or whatever in FACEIT, but eventually as my rank/rating decreases, why won't this be the same as MM (except the 'you kinda need to know all maps' difference)?**

Note: I played FACEIT only once. I haven't played competitive since 3 years ago in early 2021, except for 1 game towards the end of *CSGO*. That game was the only shorter match - MR12 I think - I've ever played. I haven't played any competitive game in *CS2*.